# IE11 throws inconsistent type errors using DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, datatables, internet-explorer-11

So i have a DataTable and sometimes it gives a typeError, and sometimes it works..

When i do a refresh sometimes the DataTable appears empty, and i get a console error saying:

***Object doesn't support property or method 'DataTable'***

Here is the error

[image]

Here is the error result

[image]

Completely empty, the only thing that comes to mind is bad library loading and i already tried many fixes.

Anyone who has experienced this bug?

**ADITIONAL INFO:**

- Project is MVC with Angular
- The browser that fires this error is IE11 (Chrome seems fine)
- There are no duplicated libraries
- Function is running as callback inside a timeOut

Comment: Obviously you have not loaded dataTables at the time the dataTable is initialized, but how and when we cannot know without seeing the source code.

Comment: It shows up as loaded, is this information misleading? 
The whole situation seems realy odd, hope the screenshot helps

http://imgur.com/PFZ9Z8M

Comment: Hey @user2790764 - you are sure the version of `jquery.dataTables.js` is +1.10.x ...? The `DataTable()` constructor was introduced 1.10.0.  You seem to use 3 different versions of jQuery? :)  Just saying, but not itself the issue I guess - but you can experience problems if you use a jQuery lower than 1.7.8 (as far as I recall) and dataTables.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @davidkonrad,


What makes this bug so weird is it being inconsistent,
why does it work on chrome and not IE?

Why does it work perfectly and then sometimes it throw this error?

I even did a JS setTimeout(callTableFucntion, 10000),
thats a 10 second delay so IE can load everything perfectly and it stil throwed this error.

Iam all out of ideias :/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, for all the people out there with this error:

I thought it was IE being retarded as usual and taking too long to load so i put the dataTables lib as first to load (next to jquery of course), ***THIS IS WRONG***

I put it in last place after EVERYTHING loaded, of course ie takes a bit more then chromes ultra V8 but everything goes smooth.

I realy hope this helps somebody that was as desperate and tired of this bug as i was, cheers.